# SQL variable in nested stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a stored procedure that retrieves last values from the specific column in a table and increments it by one based on type of document and location.

When I call this stored procedure in isolation it works perfectly. But when I nest it in another stored procedure, the value is not set to a variable `@TempLastGeneratedNumber`. When I called the stored procedure within another procedure and if I print the value of `@TempLastGeneratedNumber` it is empty.

But when I call the stored procedure in isolation I get the correct value.

This is my stored procedure

```
    Create Procedure [GenerateDocumentNo]
        @Document_Type varchar(max) = null,
        @Location_Id int = null
        @FinalNumber varchar(max) = null output
    as
    begin try
    begin tran

    Declare @TempLastGeneratedNumber varchar(max)

    if (@Document_Type = 'Apple')
    BEGIN
    Select top(1) @TempLastGeneratedNumber = Code from Apple_Details_tbl where Location_Id = @Location_Id  order by Id desc
    END

    else if (@Document_Type = 'Mango')
    BEGIN
    Select top(1) @TempLastGeneratedNumber = Code from Mango_Details_tbl where Location_Id = @Location_Id order by Id desc
    END


    if(@TempLastGeneratedNumber is not null or @TempLastGeneratedNumber != '')
    BEGIN

    Set @FinalNumber = @TempLastGeneratedNumber + 1
    END

    commit tran
    end try

    begin catch
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    if
    end catch
```

So please help me what is the issue in above stored procedure and how to solve this?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: So your `@TempLastGeneratedNumber` is of type `varchar(max)` - and then you add one to it? `Set @FinalNumber = @TempLastGeneratedNumber + 1` - how is this supposed to work??

Comment: but I did not get the value of TempLastGeneratedNumber initally where i retrive it from table.                                          Select top(1) @TempLastGeneratedNumber = Code from Apple_Details_tbl

Comment: (1) What do the calls look like?  (2) You should set the type of @TempLastGeneratedNumber to an integer.  (3) Why not just use an identity column?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff i cant use identity column as there are overall 50 different Locations and the code should be incremented by one as per Location.

Answer (score 1):

The value is NULL most likely because the queries are not returning any value or are returning a NULL value.

Presumably, this is because @Document_Type is neither "Apple" nor "Mango".  Or, because the location_id is not in the table.  Or, because the `code` on the maximum id is NULL.

Try printing out the values of the arguments when you are calling the procedure.

The other possibility is that you have not declared @FinalNumber as an output parameter on the call as well as the definition.

I do think it is bad practice to name a variable something like "whatever NUMBER" and then have its type be non-numeric.  However, I don't this is causing your problem.

Comment: Thank for Quick Suggestion Gordon Linoff. but i had already tried this earlier. Neither my @Document_Type is null nor my code. I had also declared FinalNumber as Output in parent Stored Procedure.However i was also thinking that my max code is null but if so i had hardcoded it to 1.(Modified in else Condition where i checked that TempDocumentNumber is null or '')